# How to use tidyverse to compute time series of cross-sectional correlations

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidy

I have a panel dataset. I want to compute correlations. I have already computed cross-sectional correlations now I want to compute time series means of these cross-sectional correlations. I have produced minimal example.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(corrr)

data<- tribble(
        ~year, ~V1, ~V2, ~V3, ~misc_var,
        2018,   5,   6,   5,       "a",
        2018,   4,   6,   4,       "b",
        2018,   3,   2,   3,        NA,
        2013,   5,   8,   2,       "4",
        2013,   6,   3,   8,       "8",
        2013,   4,   7,   5,        NA
)


pearson_corr<-data%>%
        select_if(is.numeric)%>%
        group_by(Month)%>%
        group_map(~correlate(.x))
```

Answer (score 0):

The precise output was not specified in the question but this produces a two column output in which the first column is the year and the second column is a list of correlation matrices.

```
library(dplyr)
library(corrr)

out <- data %>%
  select(where(is.numeric)) %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  summarize(corr = list(correlate(.[-1])), .groups = "drop")

str(out)
## tibble[,2] [2 x 2] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
##  $ year: num [1:2] 2013 2018
##  $ corr:List of 2
##   ..$ : cor_df[,4] [3 x 4] (S3: cor_df/tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
##   .. ..$ term: chr [1:3] "V1" "V2" "V3"
##   .. ..$ V1  : num [1:3] NA 0.163 0.598
##   .. ..$ V2  : num [1:3] 0.163 NA -0.371
##   .. ..$ V3  : num [1:3] 0.598 -0.371 NA
##   ..$ : cor_df[,4] [3 x 4] (S3: cor_df/tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
##   .. ..$ term: chr [1:3] "V1" "V2" "V3"
##   .. ..$ V1  : num [1:3] NA 0.163 0.598
##   .. ..$ V2  : num [1:3] 0.163 NA -0.371
##   .. ..$ V3  : num [1:3] 0.598 -0.371 NA

out$corr[[1]]
## # A tibble: 3 x 4
##   term      V1     V2     V3
##   <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
## 1 V1    NA      0.163  0.598
## 2 V2     0.163 NA     -0.371
## 3 V3     0.598 -0.371 NA
```